# My form_tag form doesn't do anything when the submit button is clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
  get "log_in" => "sessions#new", :as => "log_in"

  resources :sessions
```

sd

```
def new
end

def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])
    if user 
        session[:user_id] = User.id
    else
        flash.now.alert = "Sorry, invalid email or password!"
        render "new"
    end
end
```

as

```
<h1>Log In</h1

<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
<p class="button"><%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

Am I missing something there? It just sits here. Nothing happens. I'm expecting it to go to the sessions controller's create action, or at least give an error, but nothing, nothing at all happens when the button is clicked.

Comment: close the <p> tag first then check

Comment: And the </h1 tag as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use method post in form_tag

```
<%= form_tag sessions_path, {:method => :post} do  %>
```

and try out.

Comment: You should be able to issue a GET with forms as well.